# Copy Form of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this for exmple:

{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2}},{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}}

So now i have to copy the form of the list with oen depth less so my result would be :

{{0,0},{0},{0,0,0}}

The first list might be a millions of points long so it should be kinda time efficient.
Any Ideas would be great, Thanks in advance

Comment: While you wait for a fast answer have a play around with `{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}} /. {__Integer} -> 0`

Comment: Will it always be a 3D list where each element is a list of pairs? Or are there other possibilities? `Replace[yourlist, {_, _} -> 0, {2}]` yields the correct result, but it may not cover all the possible kinds of lists you need to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, it will always be 3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}};

  Total[list 0, {3}]
```

Or

```
Apply[Total, list 0, {2}]
```

Or

```
ConstantArray[0, #] & /@ Length /@ list
```

> {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Map[0 &, list, {2}]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}

Also

```
list /. _?VectorQ -> 0
```

> {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}